# Using .eq() and each() together

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to use **.each** to change the first option of each individual select element. The code below all works. You can see the .each being using to change (highlight) each select elements border when focused. I can't figure out how to get it to work for replacing the first options however.

```
$(".select").focusout(function() {
        $(".select").css({
            "border-color": dd_border_color,
            "box-shadow": "unset"
        });
    });

    $(".select").each(function(i) {
        $(this).focus(function() {
            $(this).css({
                "border-color": dd_border_color_s,
                "box-shadow": dd_box_shadow
            });
        });
    });


    $('.select[id*=sub1] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    $('.select[id*=sub2] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    $('.select[id*=sub3] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    $('.select[id*=sub4] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    $('.select[id*=sub5] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    $('.select[id*=sub6] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    $('.select[id*=sub7] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    $('.select[id*=sub8] option:eq(0)').replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
```

I tried:

```
       $('.select[id*=sub] option:eq(0)').each(function(i) {
        $(this).replaceWith("<option value disabled hidden></option>");
    });
```

And a number of other combinations, using .eq(0) in different places. It either replaced the first option of the first select, or did nothing at all. Once I figured out how to do this correctly, it'll help me tidy up my code across a number pages in some online quizzes I'm making.

Comment: If your'e using jQuery, handling a ton of `.class` is simple compared to a ton of `#id`.

Comment: (And if you're not using jQuery, as well.)

Comment: Try with `$('select[id^=sub]').filter(function() {return $(this).find("option:eq(0)")}).each(function(i) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

90% of the time the use of `#id` is actually a hinderance. Moreover if jQuery is used, `#id` is unnecessary 99% of the time.
`:eq()` only returns a single match. In order to use on multiple targets, it must be inside the actual loop or iteration.

Easiest way is to remove `:eq()` and simplify the selector:

```
$('.select option:first-of-type').each(function() {
```

```js
$('.select option:first-of-type').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<option selected>This is the new default option</option>");
});
```

```html
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='select'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I Reverted it back to "<option value disabled hidden></option>" - I'm using html/javascript/jquery to alter the way moodle questions behave. Your solution has worked perfectly though and I will be able to implement it in other areas. Sorry I can't upvote yet, I only registered and started to learn all of this two weeks ago, I haven't got enough reputation yet.

Comment: That's great, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with

```
$('.select option:eq(0)')
```

is it's the equivalent of

```
$('.select[id*=sub] option').first()
```

```js
console.log($("select option:eq(0)").length)
console.log($("select option:eq(0)").length === 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option></option><option></option><option></option>
</select>
<select>
<option></option><option></option><option></option>
</select>
<select>
<option></option><option></option><option></option>
</select>
```

Use [`:first-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) instead.  There are also other methods, such as `:first-of-type` and `:nth-child(1)` (1-based).

Note: [:eq(n)](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) has been deprecated from jquery

```js
console.log($("select option:first-child").length)
console.log($("select option:first-child").length === 3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option></option><option></option><option></option>
</select>
<select>
<option></option><option></option><option></option>
</select>
<select>
<option></option><option></option><option></option>
</select>
```